# Validate User Date Input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I am trying to validate proper date input in my ruby script.

When I run the script it just asks for the date twice no matter if it is correct or not.

Could someone please tell me where I went wrong?

```
def get_date(prompt="What is the date of the last scan (YYYYMMDD)")
    new_regex = /\A[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]\z/
    print prompt
    gets.chomp
    if prompt != new_regex
        puts "Please enter the date in the correct format"
        print prompt
        gets.chomp
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as it is, is trying to compare the likeness of the prompt to the regex pattern.

`/\A[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]\z/ === /\A[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]\z/` is true.

Your input is also not being captured, and thus not compared to the regex.

```
def get_date(prompt="What is the date of the last scan")
  new_regex = /\A[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]\z/
  print prompt + " (YYYYMMDD)"
  input = gets.chomp
  unless (input =~ new_regex) == 0 
    puts "Please enter the date in the correct format"
    get_date(prompt)
  end
  input 
end
```

`input =~ new_regex` will be nil (false) if there's no match.

(ps Rubyists like two spaces)

Comment: Josh, I made the changes and it did fix the double prompt, however now it is just stating that any input is valid now and doesn't bring up a second prompt at all even when data is invalid.

Comment: @Derek oops I wrote that too fast. I've corrected it with an edit :)

Comment: you are my hero, I have been racking my brain and searching all over to get this to work, I'm used to Python where things are a lot simpler lol. Either way I am learning a lot writing this Ruby Script. Can you explain the changes by chance or e-mail me the explanation so as not to clog up the valid info.

Comment: @Derek Biggest change is that you never did anything with the input-you were comparing the prompt against the Reyes, not the input. No difference from python there...